# Audio streaming with disruptions

Tags: bluetooth, audio-streaming, headphones, a2dp

I am in the process of developing an audio solution for a situation where audio packets cannot be sent for a period of 0.5s every second. I was wondering if there was a way to find an optimal balance, where for the right bitpool/sampling rate combo, I could buffer up enough audio when the BT link is good so that during the interval the BT link is bad, we could still have continuous audio?.

Comment: I doubt you can do this with any off-the-shelf Bluetooth device.  I don't think they typically have more than a couple hundred milliseconds of buffer memory.

Comment: Thanks, I have a custom audio board with 8MB serial PSRAM, which I can use to buffer up around 20s of audio. Want to know if A2DP allows something like this?